# Permissions for file and folders created or uploaded from ftp user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

When I create a folder or upload a file with ftp client and ftp user to my Ubuntu server 20.04 the folders created get permissions 0700 and the files uploaded 0600.
How can I make the folders to get permissions 0755 and the files 0644 automaticly???
Ftp user belongs to www-data group.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to uncomment local_umask=022 because default local_umask=077. 777 - 22 = 755 and 666 - 22 = 644